# How to color a selected set of variables in a ListPlot

Tags: plotting, code-request

This code:

```
data = {{161.984, 0.00840442}, {97.1036, 0.0305004}, {19.983, 
    0.0609291}, {33.6918, 0.0060476}, {29.209, 0.011549}, {21.4832, 
    0.048097}, {7.32123, 0.124789}, {135.084, 0.0419123}, {32.921, 
    0.0796488}, {141.281, 0.152104}, {16.4971, 0.0288236}, {55.2927, 
    0.0219473}, {52.9662, 0.0511422}, {45.1345, 0.0638596}, {35.6813, 
    0.0524373}, {90.2195, 0.0511422}};

keys = {"agr", "ma1", "ma10", "ma15", "ma6", "ma7", "ma9", "min", 
   "sbus", "scst", "segw", "sfin", "srtl", "stel", "str1", "swhl"};

meanX = Mean[data[[All, 1]]];
meanY = Mean[data[[All, 2]]];

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];
{ymin, ymax} = MinMax[data[[All, 2]]];

ListPlot[Table[Callout[data[[i]], keys[[i]]], {i, Length@data}], 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 3/5, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Sectoral Value Added", "Sectoral Influence Score"}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Business", 
 PlotLabel -> "Sectoral value added versus influence score", 
 Epilog -> {Red, Thickness[0.005], Dashed, 
   Line[{{meanX, ymin}, {meanX, ymax}}], 
   Line[{{xmin, meanY}, {xmax, meanY}}]}]
```

generates

[image]

I like to replace the circles for `{segw, stel, sfin, swhl, str1}` with a star shape and color them with `Red`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your definitions:

```
keys1 = {"segw", "stel", "sfin", "swhl", "str1"};

pos = Flatten[Position[keys, #] & /@ keys1, 1];

data1 = data[[Flatten@pos]];

keys2 = Delete[keys, pos];

data2 = Delete[data, pos];

ListPlot[
 {Callout @@@ Transpose[{data1, keys1}],
  Callout @@@ Transpose[{data2, keys2}]},
 PlotMarkers ->
  {Style[★, Red, 12], 
   Style[○, Blue, 10]},
 PlotRange -> All,
 AspectRatio -> 3/5,
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"Sectoral Value Added", "Sectoral Influence Score"},
 PlotTheme -> "Business",
 PlotLabel -> "Sectoral value added versus influence score",
 Prolog -> {Red, Thickness[0.002], Dashed, 
   Line[{{meanX, ymin}, {meanX, ymax}}], 
   Line[{{xmin, meanY}, {xmax, meanY}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
keys = {"agr", "ma1", "ma10", "ma15", "ma6", "ma7", "ma9", "min", 
   "sbus", "scst", "segw", "sfin", "srtl", "stel", "str1", "swhl"};

Markers = {"Circle", "Circle", "Circle", "Circle", "Circle", "Circle",
    "Circle", "Circle", "Circle", "Circle", "OpenStar", "Circle", 
   "OpenStar", "OpenStar", "OpenStar", "OpenStar"};

colors = {Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, 
   Darker[Green], Blue, Darker[Green], Darker[Green], Darker[Green], 
   Darker[Green]};

meanX = Mean[data[[All, 1]]];
meanY = Mean[data[[All, 2]]];

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];
{ymin, ymax} = MinMax[data[[All, 2]]];

ListPlot[Table[
  Callout[data[[i]], keys[[i]], CalloutMarker -> Markers[[i]], 
   CalloutStyle -> colors[[i]]], {i, Length[data]}], PlotRange -> All,
  AspectRatio -> 3/5, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05], Frame -> True,
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.001], 
 FrameLabel -> {"Sectoral Value Added", "Sectoral Influence Score"}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Business", 
 PlotLabel -> "Sectoral value added versus influence score", 
 Epilog -> {Red, Thickness[0.005], Dashed, 
   Line[{{meanX, ymin}, {meanX, ymax}}], 
   Line[{{xmin, meanY}, {xmax, meanY}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for editing :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit hack, to cover circle underneath, I increased the star size. Probably you can post process the figure you have to get you want.

```
Show[ListPlot[Table[Callout[data[[i]], keys[[i]]], {i, Length@data}], 
  PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 3/5, 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Sectoral Value Added", "Sectoral Influence Score"}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Business", 
  PlotLabel -> "Sectoral value added versus influence score", 
  Epilog -> {Red, Thickness[0.005], Dashed, 
    Line[{{meanX, ymin}, {meanX, ymax}}], 
    Line[{{xmin, meanY}, {xmax, meanY}}]}], 
 ListPlot[
  Join @@ Extract[data, 
    Position[keys, #] & /@ 
     ToString /@ {segw, stel, sfin, swhl, str1}], PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotMarkers -> {"\[FivePointedStar]", 25}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An `Association` - based solution (with callouts placed automatically)

```
asc = AssociationThread[keys -> data];

ka = {"segw", "stel", "sfin", "swhl", "str1"};

pa = KeyTake[ka] @ asc;

pb = KeyTake[Complement[keys, ka]] @ asc;

Show[
 ListPlot[pb, PlotMarkers -> Style[\[EmptyCircle], Blue, 10], PlotTheme -> "Business"],
 ListPlot[pa, PlotMarkers -> Style[\[FivePointedStar], Red, 12]],
 AspectRatio -> 3/5,
 Epilog ->
  {Red, Thickness[0.003], Dashed,
   Line[{{meanX, ymin}, {meanX, ymax}}],
   Line[{{xmin, meanY}, {xmax, meanY}}]},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"Sectoral Value Added", "Sectoral Influence Score"},
 ImageSize -> 500,
 PlotLabel -> "Sectoral value added versus influence score",
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could split your data into two sets, and plot them with different settings for `PlotStyle` and `PlotMarkers`:

```
ListPlot[
 GatherBy[Table[Callout[data[[i]], keys[[i]]], {i, Length@data}], 
  MatchQ[Callout[_, "segw" | "stel" | "sfin" | "swhl" | "str1"]]], 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 3/5, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05], Frame -> True,
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {"\[EmptyCircle]", "\[FivePointedStar]"}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Sectoral Value Added", "Sectoral Influence Score"}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Business", 
 PlotLabel -> "Sectoral value added versus influence score", 
 Epilog -> {Red, Thickness[0.005], Dashed, 
   Line[{{meanX, ymin}, {meanX, ymax}}], 
   Line[{{xmin, meanY}, {xmax, meanY}}]}]
```